# Initializer in Angular -- Make a bunch of rest calls at the start of the application before loading AppComponent (The First Component)

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I want to make a set of method calls (REST calls to populate views) at the start of the application.

So, no matter the route used to load the application (in case the user copy pastes links to different routes directly into the browser), all the views are populated before being displayed.

Currently I have an `AppInitializerService` that is injected into the constructor of the component pointed to by every route.

Is there a better way I could do this?

Comment: Can you use CanActivate guard on AppComponent? That's the easiest way of implementing "do something before component loads". And if you implement it on root component, you're actually guarding the whole application.

Comment: @ritaj This seems like a hack as in we are writing code where it need not be written and delegating responsibility to the router instead of a component/service that is responsible for the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class for component and in its ngOnInit method, call your appInitializer service to setup required infra.
All component will now derive from this class and get initialized

However, make sure that initialization is valid for the lifetime of component only. If you run code with each component on each initialization, during a workflow you will end up setting the infra several times.

But if you want initialization to happen for once, eg load resources, then AppComponent's CanActivate be a possible choice. However, canActivate is more of a permission requirement API and not an initialization purpose one. AppComponent's own constructor is better position. Even the ngOnInit will happen after the data bindings are done, so that will be delayed for the requirement.